# Accessor of an inherited, synthesized property in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, properties, subclass

I have two classes: Geometry and Circle. Circle is a subclass of Geometry.

Geometry has a synthesized property:

interface:

```
@interface Geometry : NSObject <drawProtocol, intersectionProtocol>
@property int geoLineWidth;
```

implementation:

```
@synthesize geoLineWidth;
```

Circle is a subclass of Geometry. The interface:

```
@interface Circle : Geometry
```

This code compiles, inside a method of Geometry, in Geometry.m

```
NSLog(@"%d", geoLineWidth);
```

This code does not compile, inside a method of Circle

```
NSBezierPath * thePath=  [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
[thePath setLineWidth: geoLineWidth];
```

`Use of undeclared identifier 'geoLineWidth'`

However, this code compiles:

```
[thePath setLineWidth: [self geoLineWidth]];
```

Is this behavior intentional, or am I missing something ?

Comment: Also, the subclass inherits the protocols so you don't need the < drawProtocol, etc. > part in the interface of Circle.

Comment: BTW is it possible to use the markdown tags to strike through text in the code section ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the subclass, instead of accessing the instance variable directly, you must actually use the accessor.

Change this:

```
[thePath setLineWidth: GeoLineWidth];
```

To this:

```
[thePath setLineWidth: self.GeoLineWidth];
[thePath setLineWidth: [self GeoLineWidth]];
```

To get the compiler to recognize the instance variable, you'd need explicitly to declare it in the superclass header file.

Comment: This caught me when I moved my ivar declaration block from the .h file to the .m file.

Answer (score 3):

This is intentional. Your subclass only knows about the contents of the interface file (that's all you import, isn't it?), and in there all you have is the property declaration. That gives the compiler no reason to believe that there is an instance variable called GeoLineWidth.

Answer (score 1):

A) don't use caps for variables, looks like a class...

B) if an Ivar is public or protected a subclass can access with self->Ivar.

C) since you have properties, use them and everything will work out.